# factor many mutated variables in one fell swoop

Tags: r, dplyr, r-factor, forcats

If I have 20 variables I've already recoded, why can't I pipe the mutate() into as_factor()? I don't get an error but it just doesn't do any leveling.

I can do it one by one
`df$Ethnicity %<>% as_factor()`

but I can't do:

```
df %<>% 
     mutate(
      Gender = case_when(
      Q4 == 1 ~ "Male", 
      Q4 == 2 ~ "Female",
      TRUE ~ as.character("Other")),

      Education = case_when(
        Education_n %in% c(1:4) ~ "Low", 
        Education_n %in% c(5:8) ~ "Medium", 
        Education_n %in% c(9:11) ~ "High", 
        TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
as_factor()
```

I've tried it as_factor(.) too, to no avail. Do I really have to manually wrap every case_when in `factor()`? I have twenty variables, I'd like to avoid a solution that requires writing each one out into a purr:: function or repeating wrapping factor() twenty times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to convert each column to factor you can use `across` to turn range of columns to factor.

```
df %<>% 
   mutate(
     Gender = case_when(
            Q4 == 1 ~ "Male", 
            Q4 == 2 ~ "Female",
            TRUE ~ as.character("Other")),

     Education = case_when(
        Education_n %in% c(1:4) ~ "Low", 
        Education_n %in% c(5:8) ~ "Medium", 
        Education_n %in% c(9:11) ~ "High", 
        TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>%
    mutate(across(Gender:Education, as_factor))
```

If you have an older version of `dplyr` use `mutate_at` :

```
mutate_at(vars(Gender:Education), as_factor)
```

Comment: This solution works but it also alphabetizes my factors, which is odd because the forcats as_factor documentation suggests a, z, g would remain in that order they appear. So my `Habit = case_when(
         Q40_1 == 1 ~ "Never",
         Q40_1 == 2 ~ "Sometimes",
         Q40_1 == 4 ~ "Often",
         Q40_1 == 5 ~ "Very often" ,
         TRUE ~ NA_character_)` variable becomes [1] "Often"      "Sometimes"  "Never"      "Very often". Do you have any suggestion how I could fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by `alphabetizes my factors`. Do you have an example in a reproducible format that we can test on?

Comment: Not without sharing the dataset. I meant implementing your solution will order the levels in inconsistent ways. At first I thought it was alphabetical but for two variables with the same `case_when(Q40_1 == 1 ~ "Never",
         Q40_1 == 2 ~ "Sometimes",
         Q40_1 == 4 ~ "Often",
         Q40_1 == 5 ~ "Very often" ,
         TRUE ~ NA_character_)` code order, the output order will be different: levels(df$`Habit1`)
[1] "Often"      "Sometimes"  "Never"      "Very often"
> levels(df$`Habit2`)
[1] "Never"      "Sometimes" "Very often" "Often"   neither of which is in the correct order

Comment: I don't know what is the expected correct order in your case but `as_factor` gives levels based on the order in which they appear in the vector. See the levels for `as_factor(c('A', 'E', 'D'))` vs levels for base `factor` `factor(c('A', 'E', 'D'))`. Also note that writing the condition first in `case_when` does not guarantee that the output would be in the same order as the conditions in `case_when`.

Comment: I see; yes I was expecting the order of conditions in case_when to be the order of factors. I guess there's no getting around individual releveling. Thanks for your multiple replies!